# Connecting multiple entries with class and function tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I made one program using Python (tkinter). When you click the button "Add Task" new row is created. User needs to enter values in "Size [m2]" and "Total Cost" entries, and when he/she clicks the button "Sum Values", in entry box under cost/m2 should be inserted value "Total Cost"/"Size [m2]" and sum of all values under cost/m2 (sum should be in "answerE")

I made it so that It can sum the values that are entered in entry box under cost/m2, but i cant make it to do the "Total Cost"/"Size [m2]" and to insert that answer under cost/m2 and then sums it. I always get this error:

```
CostSize=float(CostEntry.get())/float(SizeEntry.get())
NameError: name 'CostEntry' is not defined
```

And I want this:

[image]

What should I do, so that it recognizes the CostEntry?
This is the code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

myApp = Tk()
myApp.title("APP")                         
myApp.geometry("1000x650")

frame1=LabelFrame(myApp,text=" Activities ")
frame1.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=5)

i=Label(frame1, text=" i ")
i.grid(row=0,column=1)

ProjectName=Label(frame1, text=" Project name ")
ProjectName.grid(row=0,column=2)

SizeLabel=Label(frame1, text="Size [m2]")
SizeLabel.grid(row=0,column=3)

TotalCostLabel=Label(frame1, text="Total Cost")
TotalCostLabel.grid(row=0,column=4)

CostSizeLabel=Label(frame1, text="Cost/m2")
CostSizeLabel.grid(row=0,column=5)

newrow=1
class AddNewTask(object):
    rowlist=[]

    def update_row_values(self):

        for i,entry in enumerate(self.rowlist):
            entry.delete(0, 'end')
            entry.insert(0,i+1)

    def addTask(self):

        def delete():
            try:
                sum = int(answerE.get())
                entry_value = int(prodEntry.get())
                new_sum = sum - entry_value
                answerE.delete(0, 'end')
                answerE.insert(0, sum)
            except ValueError:
                pass

            bdelete.destroy()
            iEntry.destroy()
            ProjectEntry.destroy()
            SizeEntry.destroy()   
            CostEntry.destroy()
            CostSizeEntry.destroy()

            CostSizeEntry.destroy()
            self.rowlist.remove(iEntry)
            self.update_row_values()
            self.entrylist.remove(CostSizeEntry)


        global newrow
        newrow=newrow+1

        bdelete=Button(frame1,text="-",command=delete)
        bdelete.grid(row=newrow,column=0,sticky="E",padx=4)

        iEntry=Entry(frame1,width=3)
        self.rowlist.append(iEntry)     
        iEntry.grid(row=newrow,column=1,padx=1)
        n = len(self.rowlist)
        iEntry.insert(0,n)

        ProjectEntry=Entry(frame1,width=75)
        ProjectEntry.grid(row=newrow,column=2,padx=1)

        SizeEntry=Entry(frame1,width=10)
        SizeEntry.grid(row=newrow,column=3,padx=1)

        CostEntry=Entry(frame1,width=10)
        CostEntry.grid(row=newrow,column=4,padx=1)

        CostSizeEntry=Entry(frame1,width=10)
        CostSizeEntry.grid(row=newrow,column=5,padx=1)

        self.entrylist.append(CostSizeEntry)


    def __init__(self):

        buttonadd=Button(frame1,text="Add Task",command=self.addTask)
        buttonadd.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=3,pady=5)
        self.entrylist = []

    def sumValues():

        try:                                
            CostSize=float(CostEntry.get())/float(SizeEntry.get())
            CostSizeEntry.insert(0,CostSize)
        except ValueError:
            pass

        sum = 0        
        for entry in AddNewTask.entrylist:
            try:
                sum += float(entry.get())
            except ValueError:
                pass

            answerE.delete(0, 'end')
            answerE.insert(0, sum)

    sumButton = Button(frame1, text="Sum Values", command=sumValues)
    sumButton.grid(row=0, column=7)


AddNewTask=AddNewTask()


frame2=LabelFrame(myApp,text=" Answer")
frame2.grid(row=0,column=1,padx=5,sticky="N")

answerL=Label(frame2, text="Answer:  ")
answerL.grid(row=0,column=0)

answerE=Entry(frame2,width=10)
answerE.grid(row=0, column=1)

myApp.mainloop()
```

Comment: _"but i cant make it to do the "Total Cost"/"Size [m2]"..."_ - why can't you? What problem are you having?

Comment: Please check out the code , I update it.  I always get this error:

CostSize=float(CostEntry.get())/float(SizeEntry.get())
NameError: name 'CostEntry' is not defined

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] specific to your issue. Don't just dump your entire code here.

Comment: CostEntry is only defined under the scope that the method it is in...

Comment: I know, code is big,  but If I remove some part of the code, the other part will not work.
I do not know how to fix the problem that I have. I tried to do what I got in the comment but It didnt work

Answer (score 2):

The CostEntry variable is created in a class method. However, it is created with local scope. This means that when the method ends, so does the reference to CostEntry. And the next time you call the method (to destroy the object), it doesn't exist.

Solution: Use the `self` attribute to create an instance of the variable.

```
self.CostEntry=Entry(frame1,width=10)
self.CostEntry.grid(row=newrow,column=4,padx=1)
```

and when you go to delete it:

```
self.CostEntry.destroy()
```

Comment: It works if you change the `self.entrylist.remove(CostSizeEntry)` to `self.entrylist.remove(self.CostSizeEntry)`. Just missed one of the method variables. Now you should be good to go :)

Comment: No, it does not. I saw that, I did that a couple of hours ago but it still does not work. Its not the probelm only in CostEntry, its in all entries under the sumValues function.
When I do what you told me, program does not work, and when I try to delete the row, it shows bug

Comment: Not sure what the problem is because I can't reproduce the error with the fix applied. I ran it with the fix before posting the solution. I added a single row. Then pressed the "-" button and it deleted the row without reporting any errors.

Comment: try to add more than 1 row. You will see the error. Also, when i click the Sum Values button, program does not calculate" Total Cost"/"Size [m2]"  and does not input it in entry under the cost/m2 column

Answer (score 0):

You should use `self` attribute with variables that are used out of local scope. Try this:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

myApp = Tk()
myApp.title("APP")                         
myApp.geometry("1000x650")

frame1=LabelFrame(myApp,text=" Activities ")
frame1.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=5)

i=Label(frame1, text=" i ")
i.grid(row=0,column=1)

ProjectName=Label(frame1, text=" Project name ")
ProjectName.grid(row=0,column=2)

SizeLabel=Label(frame1, text="Size [m2]")
SizeLabel.grid(row=0,column=3)

TotalCostLabel=Label(frame1, text="Total Cost")
TotalCostLabel.grid(row=0,column=4)

CostSizeLabel=Label(frame1, text="Cost/m2")
CostSizeLabel.grid(row=0,column=5)

newrow=1
class AddNewTask(object):
    rowlist=[]

    def update_row_values(self):

        for i,entry in enumerate(self.rowlist):
            entry.delete(0, 'end')
            entry.insert(0,i+1)

    def addTask(self):

        def delete():
            try:
                sum = int(answerE.get())
                entry_value = int(prodEntry.get())
                new_sum = sum - entry_value
                answerE.delete(0, 'end')
                answerE.insert(0, sum)
            except ValueError:
                pass

            bdelete.destroy()
            iEntry.destroy()
            ProjectEntry.destroy()
            self.SizeEntry.destroy()   
            self.CostEntry.destroy()
            self.CostSizeEntry.destroy()

            self.rowlist.remove(iEntry)
            self.update_row_values()
            self.entrylist.remove(CostSizeEntry)


        global newrow
        newrow=newrow+1

        bdelete=Button(frame1,text="-",command=delete)
        bdelete.grid(row=newrow,column=0,sticky="E",padx=4)

        iEntry=Entry(frame1,width=3)
        self.rowlist.append(iEntry)     
        iEntry.grid(row=newrow,column=1,padx=1)
        n = len(self.rowlist)
        iEntry.insert(0,n)

        ProjectEntry=Entry(frame1,width=75)
        ProjectEntry.grid(row=newrow,column=2,padx=1)

        self.SizeEntry=Entry(frame1,width=10)
        self.SizeEntry.grid(row=newrow,column=3,padx=1)

        self.CostEntry=Entry(frame1,width=10)
        self.CostEntry.grid(row=newrow,column=4,padx=1)

        self.CostSizeEntry=Entry(frame1,width=10)
        self.CostSizeEntry.grid(row=newrow,column=5,padx=1)

        self.entrylist.append(self.CostSizeEntry)


    def __init__(self):

        buttonadd=Button(frame1,text="Add Task",command=self.addTask)
        buttonadd.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=3,pady=5)
        self.entrylist = []

        self.sumButton = Button(frame1, text="Sum Values", command=self.sumValues)
        self.sumButton.grid(row=0, column=7)


    def sumValues(self):

        try:                                
            CostSize=float(self.CostEntry.get())/float(self.SizeEntry.get())
            self.CostSizeEntry.insert(0,CostSize)
        except ValueError:
            pass

        sum = 0        
        for entry in AddNewTask.entrylist:
            try:
                sum += float(entry.get())
            except ValueError:
                pass

            answerE.delete(0, 'end')
            answerE.insert(0, sum)



AddNewTask=AddNewTask()


frame2=LabelFrame(myApp,text=" Answer")
frame2.grid(row=0,column=1,padx=5,sticky="N")

answerL=Label(frame2, text="Answer:  ")
answerL.grid(row=0,column=0)

answerE=Entry(frame2,width=10)
answerE.grid(row=0, column=1)

myApp.mainloop()
```

Comment: Sorry but it does not work. There are two errors.
First, when I try to delete rows with "-" button, it does not work>
Second,  it does not inserts value in every entry under cost/m2.